# How do you redo children's paralogues?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

Throughout the game, I have unlocked the paralogue for the children and have successfully recruited a fair few. However, I have come across some that either die in their paralogue or I don't fulfil a requirement in the mission for me to recruit them. Is there a way to redo this so I can recruit all of the children?

Comment: Do you mean the ones you did not unlock died before you could talk to them or was that the case for all of them?

Comment: yeah, the ones that died before I could talk to them

Answer (score 2):

Children that are killed in the paralogue cannot be recruited after the paralogue. If you have saved since completing the paralogue then there is no way to get the child unless you restart to a point before this quest. If you want all the children you should restart the game and save before you try and complete the paralogue in case you lose a child.